# Node.js server / express module not sending data to client

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

UPDATE

I changed the code, as of advice from @AndrewNolan, to a promise chain using `async waterfall` and `async series` from:

https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#waterfall

https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#series

There is no issue with `app.use` being recognised but nothing is sent to the client.

The `console.log` inside the `router.get` doesn't log anything but the one outisde does.

```
// collect data from the database associated with user on login
app.post('/login', function(request, response, callback) {

  // outline the parameters for the login
  var parameters = [ request.body.input.sessionAppID, request.body.input.sessionUserID ];

  // outline an async waterfall to collect the login details
  async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {

      // create a new mongo client for collecting the details of the user
      var client = new MongoClient(url, mongoOptions);

      // call the async function to collect the user details
      loginUser(parameters, client).then(function(user) {

        // close the client after the user details have been collected
        client.close().then(function() {
          // set the callback for the first waterfall as the user
          callback(null, user);
        })
      });
    },
    function(user, callback) {

      // set the application id of the login
      var application = user.appID;

      // set an async series of functions to collect the login information
      async.series({
        readings: function(callback) {

          // create a new mongo client for collecting the users devices
          var client = new MongoClient(url, mongoOptions);

          // call the async function to collect the devices of the user
          readings(user, client).then(function(readings) {

            // close the client after the readings have been collected
            client.close().then(function() {

              // set the callback for the first waterfall as the user
              callback(null, readings);
            })
          })
        },
        alerts: function(callback) {
          // create a new mongo client for collecting the users devices
          var client = new MongoClient(url, mongoOptions);

          // call async function to collect login alerts
          loginAlerts(application, client).then(function(alerts) {

            // close the client after the alerts have been collected
            client.close().then(function() {

              // set the callback for the alerts
              callback(null, alerts);
            })
          })
        },
        polygons: function(callback) {
          // create a new mongo client for collecting the users devices
          var client = new MongoClient(url, mongoOptions);

          // call async function to collect the polygons on loginUser
          loginPolygons(application, client).then(function(polygons) {

            // close the client after the polygons have ben collected
            client.close().then(function() {

              // callback when the login polygons are collected
              callback(null, polygons)
            })
          })
        }
      },
      function(err,results) {

        // create a router to send data to the client / webpage
        var router = new express.Router();

        // send login data to the webpage as json
        router.get('/loginData', cors(), function(req, res) {

          console.log(results);
          // convert the login data to a string
          var dataJSON = JSON.stringify(results);

        });

        // send the login data to the client webpage
        app.use('/', router);
      })
    }
  ])
});
```

Does that mean the `router module` isn't working?

Comment: It is a suggestion that you chain promises together instead of nesting them inside one another. Also, you shouldnt nest app.get / app.post inside another app.post.

Comment: @AndrewNolan Thank you. I'm currently sorting it now and seems to be working. I'm using the async library with the waterfall and series control flows

Comment: @AndrewNolan I can't seem to get the app.get outside of the orignal app.post. Do you know of any way to do this? Would putting the app.get in a function take it ouside of the app.post?

Answer (score 0):

I added a `function` in to the end of the `async series` which passses the `results` as an argument in order to take the `app.get` outside and not nest it.

I also changed it to `app.get` rather than `app.use`

This is the end of the `async series` where the new `function` is called:

```
      function(err,results) {

        // call function to send login data to the client
        sendLoginData(results);
      })
```

This is the new `function` which uses `app.get` to send the data to the client:

```
// function to send login data to the client
function sendLoginData(data) {

  // send the login data to the client webpage
  app.get('/loginData', (req, res) => {
    res.json(data);
  });
};
```